Link contribution to case
I know it is possible to add expense to a case.
But is it possible to link contribution  to a case?
Thanks you.

Welcome to CiviCRM Stackexchange,
Might this extension help https://github.com/pradpnayak/org.civicoop.casecontribution
Alternatively, you can create a Custom field for the case as a Contribution entity reference. If you use a custom field then you can use this field in Searchkit if you want to build a report
